# How to change csv to json array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an external CSV file into a JOSN Array in my JS Code.

I tried lots of codes, with no luck like this:

```js
var map = {};
var rows = csv.split(/\n/g);
var keys = rows.shift().split(",");
rows.forEach(raw_row => {
  var row = {};
  var row_key;
  var columns = raw_row.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
  columns.forEach((column, index) => {
    var key = keys[index];
    if (!key) return;
    if (key === 'Name') {
      row_key = column;
      return;
    }
    if (key === "Coordinates") {
      column = column.replace(/""/g, '"');
      column = column.substring(1, column.length - 1);
      column = column.replace(/([a-zA-Z_]+):/g, `"$1":`);
      try {
        column = JSON.parse(`{${column}}`);
      } catch (e) {}
    }

    row[key] = column;
  });
  map[row_key] = row;
});
console.log(map);
```

but I believe my expectation is something else, so I dont get what I want.
could some one pleae help me to change this csv(file):

> contry;fromNr;toNr;Type;cust_1;cust_2
> US;0;100;wood;max;nuk
> DE;100;500;metal;max;pal

into JSON Array:

```json
[{
  "country": "US",
  "fromNr": 0,
  "toNr": 100,
  "Type": "wood",
  "cust_1": "max",
  "cust_2": "nuk"
}, {
  "country": "DE",
  "fromNr": 100,
  "toNr": 500,
  "Type": "metal",
  "cust_1": "max"
}]
```

Comment: Why are you using `rows.shift().split(",")`? Your column names and values are delimited by ";". It should be `rows.shift().split(";")`.

Comment: its just one of the codes which I tried. could you create one please?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, there are existing solutions for this, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser)

Comment: Maybe not what you want -but I saved myself a lot of headaches by using a CSV parsing library: `Papa Parse`. It also converts to JSON.

Comment: @Kokodoko I tried it, but the result come something wich I cant use it. I'll try it again. tnx anyway

Comment: @dirkenstocks: what is this? $ npm install csv-parser. should i install on my computer?

Comment: It's a Node.js package that provides the functionality that you desire. Node is kind of the defacto JS runtime. NPM is Node Package Manager, a way for you to bring published packages into your own projects.

Comment: @hamid you can check my solution, If you want to understand how it can be done in JS. But There will be many JS library that will handle different corner cases with additional functionality, So check them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below function `csvIntoJson` to convert.

```
    const csv = 'contry;fromNr;toNr;Type;cust_1;cust_2\nUS;0;100;wood;max;nuk\nDE;100;500;metal;max;pal';

const csvIntoJson = (csv, separator) => {
  let [headers, ...rows] = csv.split('\n');
  headers = headers.split(separator);
  rows = rows.map(row => row.split(separator));

  return rows.reduce((jsonArray, row) => {
    const item = row.reduce((item, value, index) => {
      return {...item, [headers[index]]: value};
    }, {});
    return jsonArray.concat(item);
  }, []);
};

const jsonArray = csvIntoJson(csv, ';');
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use my external csv file which is already on my Server? how can i use it? because I want it to be changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion use a library, But you still want to understand how it can be done then here is the simple code.

I have used **','** delimiter, You can change it to **';'** or anything else as per your usecase.

**steps:**

1. Read csv as text
2. split text by new line to get rows
3. split row by delimiter like ',' or ';'
4. Do your stuff

**code:**

```js
 function Upload(input){
        console.log("uploading");
        let file = input.files[0];

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsText(file);

        
        reader.onload = function() {
            map_object = [];
            console.log(reader.result);
            var textByLine = (reader.result).split("\n")
            console.log(textByLine);

            // read header
            header = (textByLine[0]).split(',');
            // read data
            for(var i = 1 ; i< textByLine.length -1; i++){
                temp_row = {}
                row_data = textByLine[i].split(',');
                for (var j = 0 ; j< header.length; j++){
                    temp_row[header[j]] = row_data[j]
                } 
                console.log(temp_row);

                map_object.push(temp_row);
            }
            console.log(map_object);
            document.write(JSON.stringify(map_object));
            
        };

        reader.onerror = function() {
            console.log(reader.error);
        };
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept='.csv' onchange="Upload(this)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use my external csv file which is already on my Server? how can i use it? because I want it to be changed automatically.

Comment: You didn't mention in the question that the file is on server. In that case I am assuming you are using node js!! Then just use a csv parser to read the file from the required path. Such as [fast csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) or [node csv](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. shold i install it? where? on my local pc or there is a link to add to my code like JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = "contry;fromNr;toNr;Type;cust_1;cust_2\nUS;0;100;wood;max;nuk\nDE;100;500;metal;max;pal";

function CSVtoJSON(csv) {
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];

    var headers = lines[0].split(";");
    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split(";");
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);

    }
    return result; 
}

console.log(CSVtoJSON(data));
```